# Warning C4477 'wprintf_s' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'wchar_t *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

**When I am compiling my C++ project, I am getting the below warning message:**

> Warning   C4477   'wprintf_s' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'wchar_t *', but variadic argument 1 has type
>   `std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>`

**The error is when calling,**

```
wstring(featureList)
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
CString featureList;

MyLog(L"featureList1.Replace(restoken + L\"; \", L\"= 1; \") list : %s",wstring(featureList));
```

When I cast with c_str() like as shown below, then the warning is resolved.

```
wstring(featureList).c_str()
```

**Can I proceed with this fix?**

Comment: Use %hs to pass an 8-bit encoded string.

Comment: @HansPassant: That was an unfortunate bit of formatting; fixed.

Comment: @MSalters, the recommendation doesn't have anything to do with the formatting of the question.  %hs simply avoids having to jump through the wstring conversion hoop, he can pass the CString directly.

Comment: @HansPassant: Doesn't that assume that `CString` is a `CStringA` instead of a `CStringW` ? `%s` always works with `CString`.

Comment: If it is actually a CStringW then he has one more reason not to use wstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The `wstring` is a temporary, but its lifetime only ends after `wsprintf_s` returns.

As an MSVC++ extension, you can also omit the `wstring` altogether and pass the `featureList` as-is. In standard C++ this is Undefined Behavior but Microsoft wrote `CString` so that works with their own compiler.